# How to fix the block size in external databricks tables?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a SQL notebook to change data and insert into another table.

I have a situation when I'm trying to change the storaged block size in blobStorage, I want to have less and bigger files. I try change a lot of parameters.

So i found a behaviour.

When I run the notebook the command create the files with almost 10MB for each.

If I create the table internaly in databricks and run another comand

create external_table as

select * from internal_table

the files had almost 40 MB...

So my question is..

There is a way to fix the minimal block size in external databricks tables?
When i'm transforming data in a SQL Notebook we have best pratices? like transform all data and store locally so after that move the data to external source?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _"block size"_ ???? What you report is the _file_ size; and while HDFS has a concept of "block" for internal purposes, BLOB storage has no such concept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark doesn't have a straightforward way to control the size of output files. One method people use is to call `repartition` or `coalesce` to the number of desired files. To use this to control the size of output files, you need to have an idea of how many files you want to create, e.g. to create 10MB files, if your output data is 100MB, you could call `repartition(10)` before the write command.

It sounds like you are using Databricks, in which case you can use the `OPTIMIZE` command for Delta tables. Delta's `OPTIMIZE` will take your underlying files and compact them for you into approximately 1GB files, which is an optimal size for the JVM in large data use cases.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/optimize.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not using delta tables and I'm not using spark to tranform data. We are using SQL notebooks.. so it seems more difficult

Comment: Databricks notebooks **always** use Spark. And there's an equivalent to `repartition` in SparkSQL using a workaround i.e. `SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions =` then a `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause >> https://deepsense.ai/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter great... Thanks for your answer using `SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions =` i solved my problem